# VHDL Array Initialization Error: "Syntax error near ":="

Tags: vhdl

I have a written code for Array Initialization. but it shows me following Error.

> ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "Syntax error near ":=".
>
> ERROR:HDLCompiler:854 - Unit  ignored due to previous errors.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity kelvin is
end kelvin;

architecture ospl of kelvin is
type array_new is array (0 to 1) of integer;

begin
array_new := ('127','126');
    
end ospl;
```

Comment: I think you need to take a step back and learn some more VHDL first. Try the VHDL Background link on [this page](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl_designers_guide/) of my company's website. Specifically, `array_new` is a _type_, not an _object_; you can't assign values to it, you need to declare an object (eg signal, variable) of that type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have done is declared an array type with the name `array_new` and you are directly assigning it a value. You have missed a step in between which is declaring an object of your array type.

After the line of code

```
type array_new is array (0 to 1) of integer;
```

you should declare a signal with of the type `array_new`. For e.g. the modified code will look like:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity kelvin is
end kelvin;

architecture ospl of kelvin is
type array_new is array (0 to 1) of integer;
signal array_new_signal: array_new;

begin
array_new_signal <= (127,126);

end ospl;
```

[Refer this link for further explanation:](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/arrays.html)

Comment: I am getting errro @array_new_signal <= ('127','126'); line

Comment: @KelvinKalariya - i'm sorry for the late reply, removing the single quotes will solve the problem.